# Remove numbers and characters only from string

Tags: c#, regex

Given a string containing numbers and characters eg

Mi2ch£al

What would be the relevant regex to remove everything *but* letters (therefore numbers and characters)?

Also, I am using .NET 2.0 for this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string s = "Mi2ch£al";
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"[^\w\s]", "");
```

and if you don't want international accented characters:

```
string s = "Mi2ch£al";
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]", "");
```

Comment: Actually that's another important feature: I dont want international accented characters too!

Answer (score 2):

If you dont mind using Linq :

```
string s = new string("Mi2ch£al".Where(c => !char.IsNumber(c) && !char.IsLetter(c)).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

replace regex `[^a-zA-Z]` with empty string or `[^a-zA-Z\s]` it's save spaces

Answer (score 0):

`\p{L}` matches any character that is a letter, and `\P{L}` any character that is not a letter (including non-Latin character sets, accented characters, etc.).  Thus, you could simply use:

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"\P{L}", String.Empty)
```

where `input` is the input string.